# Как соединить SUM(duration) с двумя JOIN

Tags: sql

Не могу понять как правильно написать SUM(duration) (надо посчитать кол-во часов всех курсов)

```
SELECT Students.name, Courses.duration FROM Courses
  JOIN Subscriptions ON Courses.id = Subscriptions.course_id
  JOIN Students ON Students.id = Subscriptions.student_id;
```

Comment: два джойна тут ни на что не влияют. добавьте в запрос суммирование и группировку и все.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста по подробнее я в начало написал запрос SUM(duration) в конец запроса написал GROUP BY выдает ошибку https://prnt.sc/rw8lpq

Comment: вам надо группировать по полю name, суммировать поле duration. К какому-то полю применется функция агрегат, а остальные поля уходят в выражение group-by. Не должно нигде оставаться полей которые ни в группировке не участвую, ни в функциях не задействованы.

Comment: понял вас спасибо вам за ответ все получилось